# Regex to split number and string except for ordinal indicators

Tags: c#, regex

Looking for a Regex to introduce a space where numbers and strings are concatenated in user input, except for the ordinal indicators e.g. 1st, 11th, 22nd, 33rd, 44th etc.

So this string:

> Hi is this available 18dec to 21st dec

is returned as

> Hi is this available 18 dec to 21st dec

Using this expression

```
 Regex.Replace(value, @"(\d)(\p{L})", "$1 $2"))
```

gives

> Hi is this available 18 dec to 21 st dec

EDIT:

As per the comment from @juharr  dec12th should be changed to dec 12th

Comment: And you'd want "dec12th" to be changed to "dec 12th" correct?

Comment: @juharr Correct

Comment: @MatthewEvans Then please add this requirement to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  - have done

Comment: That really makes it all harder, I will update the code.

Comment: Got it finally, posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a solution like:

```
var s = "Hi is this available 18dec to 21st dec 2nd dec 1st jan dec12th";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\p{L})?(\d+)(st|[nr]d|th|(\p{L}+))", repl);
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => Hi is this available 18 dec to 21st dec 2nd dec 1st jan dec 12th

// This is the callback method that does all the work
public static string repl(Match m) 
{
    var res = new StringBuilder();
    res.Append(m.Groups[1].Value);  // Add what was matched in Group 1
    if (m.Groups[1].Success)        // If it matched at all...
        res.Append(" ");            // Append a space to separate word from number
    res.Append(m.Groups[2].Value);  // Add Group 2 value (number)
    if (m.Groups[4].Success)        // If there is a word (not st/th/rd/nd suffix)...
        res.Append(" ");            // Add a space to separate the number from the word
    res.Append(m.Groups[3]);         // Add what was captured in Group 3
    return res.ToString();
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/qrFfKA).

The regex used is

```
(\p{L})?(\d+)(st|[nr]d|th|(\p{L}+))
```

See [its demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cp%7BL%7D%29%3F%28%5Cd%2B%29%28st%7C%5Bnr%5Dd%7Cth%7C%28%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%29%29&i=Hi%20is%20this%20available%2018dec%20to%2021st%20dec%202nd%20dec%201st%20jan%0D%0Adec12th&o=e). It matches:

- `(\p{L})?` - an optional Group 1 matching a single letter
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(st|[nr]d|th|(\p{L}+))` - Group 3 matching the following alternatives

  - `st` -  `st`
  - `[nr]d` - `nd` or `rd`
  - `th` - `th`
  - `(\p{L}+)` - Group 4: any 1 or more Unicode letters

The `repl` callback method takes the match object and uses additional logic to build the correct replacement string based on whether the optional groups matched or not.

Pass the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option if you need a case insensitive search and replace, and `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` if you only want to match ASCII digits with `\d` (note that `\p{L}` will still match any Unicode letter even if you pass this option to the regex).

Comment: @MatthewEvans But you have plenty of time to ask additional questions. See juharr's comment under the question.